# Apache Proxying to Subdirectory doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a .NET app running on port 5000 and a node.js app running on port 8080. I want to forward requests to the /app directory to the node application. I have the following configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost     On
    ProxyPass             / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse      / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPass             /app/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse      /app/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ErrorLog              /var/log/httpd/amnathrig-error.log
    CustomLog             /var/log/httpd/amnathrig-access.log common
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/amnathrig.app/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/amnathrig.app/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/amnathrig.app/chain.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/amnathrig.app/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

However, requests to /app are still being forwarded to the root application. I'm fairly new to this so it might be something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [mod_proxy docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins.

So, since the first directive in your config is to proxy `/`, which will match every URI, the second `ProxyPass` is a no-op. You should sort your `ProxyPass` rules so that the most specific ones are the first in the config file.